# Convertors for JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, managed-bean

I am getting the following error: `Conversion Error setting value 'home' for 'null Converter'.` `Home` is the string representation of what is being displayed.

To me, this doesnt make sense. Here is the JSF code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{createResourceDialogController.selectedDir}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{createResourceDialogController.dirs}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And here is the ManagedBean code:

```
public Map<String,IDir> getDirs()
{
    Map<String,IDir> retVal = new LinkedHashMap<String, IDir>();
    List<IDir> dirs;
    if(isCompanyResource)
    {
        dirs = convertToIDir(getCompanyDir());
    }
    else
    {
        dirs = convertToIDir(getUserDir());
    }
    for(IDir iDir : dirs)
    {
        retVal.put(iDir.getDir(),iDir);
    }
    return retVal;
}

public IDir getSelectedDir()
{
    return selectedDir;
}

public void setSelectedDir(IDir selectedDir)
{
    this.selectedDir = selectedDir;
}
```

To me, it appears that all the types match up and that converter isn't even necessary. The `getDirs()` returns a map whose value is `IDir`. When the setter gets called, it should be getting the `IDir`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF converts your `<h:selectOneMenu />` in an html `select`, which has only value and label attributes in plain text. So you need to use a converter for that, or also you can create a `SelectItem` list with id-label values and when you receive the form just reload `IDir` with the id.

**xhtml**

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{createResourceDialogController.selectedDirId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{createResourceDialogController.options}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Backing Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CreateResourceDialogController {

    private List<SelectItem> options;

    private String selectedDirId;

    private void initBean(){
        options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        SelectItem item1 = new SelectItem(dir.getId.toString(), dir.getName());
        options.add(item1);
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getOptions(){
        return options;
    }

    public void setSelectedDirId(String dirId){
        selectedDirId = dirId;
    }

    public String getSelectedDirId(){
        return selectedDirId;
    }
}
```

Take a look to this [tutorial](http://tunatore.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/how-to-use-hselectonemenu-jsf-2-0-example/). However you should consider going through a converter if you are going to reuse this code several times, as a cleaner solution.